# Fail A Jenkins Build When Artifatory Plugin Cannot Find All Artifacts

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have a Gradle build that runs in Jenkins and Deploys to Artifactory using the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins. Right now if one of the artifacts is missing a message, "Skipping non-existent file ...", is placed in the console output.

Is it possible to fail the Jenkins job if some of the artifacts are missing?

Can I make sure it only deploys to Artifactory if **all** of the artifacts are present?

Comment: I guess you are trying to fight the symptom (incomplete deployments) instead of the root cause. You have to investigate how happens that Gradle expects some file to present, and it is not there. Is there something in the process of your build that deletes/moves some files?

Comment: @JBaruch I do not want to "fight" the symptom, I want to be notified when it occurs so that I can investigate and fix the issue. I am concerned about  Jenkins reporting a "success" when the job was not successful.